# How to cheaply assign C-style array to std::vector?

Tags: c++, arrays, stl, vector, stdvector

Currently I do the following:

```
// float *c_array = new float[1024];

void Foo::foo(float *c_array, size_t c_array_size) {
  //std::vector<float> cpp_array;

  cpp_array.assign(c_array, c_array + c_array_size);
  delete [] c_array;
}
```

How can I optimize this assigning? I would like not to perform elementwise copy but just swap pointers.

Comment: Without. But C++0x method would be also nice to see.

Comment: This isn't actually a duplicate question. The linked question only addresses going from vector to array, not from array to vector.

Comment: @ariddell Indeed. The linked question was edited to include this, but that was nearly a year after the initial asking, and none of the answers actually address that part of the question.

Comment: Any update for 2018?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The current `std::vector` doesn't provide any capability or interface to take ownership of previously allocated storage. Presumably it would be too easy to pass a stack address in by accident, allowing more problems than it solved.

If you want to avoid copying into a vector, you'll either need to use vectors through your entire call chain, or do it the C way with `float[]` the entire time. You can't mix them. You *can* guaranteed that `&vec[0]` will be equivalent to the C-array though, fully contiguous, so using vector in the whole program may be feasible.

Comment: Is this still the case currently?

Comment: @Jay yes it is.

Comment: wow, c++ will let you shoot yourself in the foot in so many ways why draw the line here

Answer (score 6):

Currently, the `std::vector` interface does not possess the capacity to move from or swap with anything except another `std::vector`.

Comment: And it's unlikely to in the future. Most use cases where you would want this you can use the raw array instead, and the additional bookkeeping added to std::vector would be horrible.

Comment: I *think* that there was at least a proposal in C++0x that would allow for this to happen. However, I'm not totally sure.

Comment: @Mark: it wouldn't require additional bookkeeping, really, if the vector takes ownership of the memory. But there are so many ways such a feature could be used wrong, I'm sure your assessment of the likeliness is accurate.

Answer (score 5):

The only way to do it would be to create a custom allocator.

1. Write an allocator class that you can initialise with your array.
2. Instantiate the vector with the allocator as an argument.

Comment: This isn't as useful as you might think, since the vector will overwrite any pre-existing data.

Comment: @geotavros -- I'll have to dig out a manual.  I haven't written a custom allocator for ages.  I'm not sure if I can work around the problem that Dennis points out.  Possibly not, but I'll try to find time to look at it some time soon.

Answer (score 1):

Unlikely it's possible - it's quite dangerous, because std::vector doesn't know how the memory was allocated and how it should be freed.

If it's possible, you may replace original allocation with creation of std::vector of correct size. It uses contiguous memory area, so it can replace manually allocated buffer.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with the use of a custom allocator. I checked on godbolt.org with clang and gcc. To me, it looks a bit of an ugly hack – but it works at least as a proof of concept.

Of course, you have to take care of the lifetime of the array for yourself.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

// custom allocator
template <typename T>
class my_allocator {
  private:
    T* const addr;
  public:
    template <typename U>
    struct rebind {
      typedef my_allocator<U> other;
    };

    //provide the required no-throw constructors / destructors:
    constexpr my_allocator(T* addr_) : addr(addr_) { };
    constexpr my_allocator(const my_allocator<T>& rhs) : addr(rhs.addr) { };
    template <typename U>
    my_allocator(const my_allocator<U>& rhs, T* addr_) : addr(addr_) { };
    ~my_allocator()  { };

    //import the required typedefs:
    using value_type=T;
    using pointer=T*;
    using reference=T&;
    using const_pointer=const T*;
    using const_reference=const T&;
    using size_type=size_t;
    using difference_type=ptrdiff_t;

  constexpr pointer   allocate(size_type n, const void * = 0) {
              pointer t=addr;
              std::cout
              << "  used my_allocator to allocate   at address "
              << t << " (+)" << std::endl;
              return addr;
            }

    constexpr void      deallocate(void* p, size_type) {
        if (p) {
        std::cout
        << "  used my_allocator to deallocate at address "
        << p << " (-)" << 
        std::endl;
        } 
    }

    template< class U, class... Args >
    void construct( U* p, Args&&... args ) {
        // avoids initialisation of the elements.
        std::cout << "Contruct called" << std::endl;
    }

};

// helper function for easy useage
template<typename T>
const std::vector<T, my_allocator<T> > CreateVectorFromArray(T* array, int size) {
    const my_allocator<T> alloc=my_allocator<T>(array);
    std::vector<int, my_allocator<int> > vecAll(size, my_allocator<int>(array));
    return vecAll;
}

template<typename T>
using element_type_t = std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*std::begin(std::declval<T&>()))>;

template<typename AR>
auto CreateVectorFromArrayAr(AR& array) {
    using T=element_type_t<AR>;
    const my_allocator<T> alloc=my_allocator<T>(array);
    std::vector<T, my_allocator<T> > vecAll(sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]), my_allocator<T>(array));
    return vecAll;
}

int main() {
    int array[]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    std::cout << "Array:  " << &array[0] << " " << array[0]  << " " << array[1]<< " " << array[2] << std::endl;

    auto vecAll=CreateVectorFromArray(array, sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]));
    auto vec3=CreateVectorFromArrayAr(array);


    std::cout << "Vector: " << &vecAll[0] << " " << vecAll[0] << " " << vecAll[1]<< " " << vecAll[2] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Array:  " << &array[0] << " " << array[0]  << " " << array[1] << " " << array[2] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "vec3:   " << &vec3[0] << " " << vec3[0]  << " " << vec3[1] << " " << vec3[2] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "sizeof(vecAll)=" << sizeof(vecAll) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "sizeof(void*)=" << sizeof(void*) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```