# declaring a vector-using function within extern "C"{}

Tags: c++

I have one file (*FILE_A.cpp*) with a function's body as follows:

```
vector<char *> lines_vector;
foo(my_file_path, "zzz", lines_vector, fout);
```

`foo` is defined in another file (*FILE_B.cpp*):

```
void foo(char * in_file, char * keyword, vector<char *>& lines_vector, FILE * fout)
```

Since *FILE_A.cpp* uses *FILE_B.cpp*'s function, it includes its headed, and here's the problem:

FILE_B.h has all of its function headers inside a

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
...
void foo(char * in_file, char * keyword, vector<char *>& lines_vector, FILE * fout)
...
#ifdef __cplusplus
};
#endif
```

and when trying to add my function it doesn't recognize the vector. The errors given are

> 1) expected ',' or '...' before '<' token
>
> 2) expected initializer before '}' token
>
> 3) 'vector' has not been declared

which makes me suspect that `extern C` can't parse this. Is there a problem in using cpp objects inside `extern "C" {}` or is there another problem here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Declarations inside `extern "C"` need to be *plain* C, not C++. IANALL, can't say what's "the law" by the C++ standard, but, some compilers will report an error (and they *should*), some a warning and some will just "go on", but, it's next to impossible to make this work, since `std::vector<>` is a template.

Answer (score 5):

the problem is: you cannot use C++ objects in C interfaces. How would do create such an object from the C side then?

So you have to change your call to:

```
void foo(char * in_file, char * keyword, char **lines_vector, int, lines_vector_size, FILE * fout)
```

then as you cannot map a vector to a buffer ([How to cheaply assign C-style array to std::vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836324/how-to-cheaply-assign-c-style-array-to-stdvector)), so to use a `vector` you'd need to create a `vector<char *>` work object and copy the data (only the pointers should be ok), work with it in your algorithm, then copy the vector data back to `lines_vector` (or if the pointers didn't change, just do nothing)

untested, I'd do naively as follows

```
void foo(char * in_file, char * keyword, char **lines_array, int, lines_array_size, FILE * fout)
{
     std::vector<char *> lines_vector;
     for (int i=0;i<lines_array_size;i++)
     {
        lines_vector.push_back(lines_array[i]);
     }

}
```

If the pointers themselves have been updated, you have to free the old ones and copy the new ones to the C structure. I'm not sure of what is the context, but this aspect is touchy (who's responsible for the allocated memory of each string...)

Answer (score 4):

C doesn't know about templates.

`std::vector<>` is a class template.

It is thus impossible to use class templates while requesting for C-like linking with `extern "C"` since it can't distinguish `std::vector<int>` from `std::vector<char>` inside the linker without using name mangling.