# Passing a double pointer as argument to a function which expects a reference to a std::vector<double>

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there any possible way to pass pointer to a double (`double *`) as argument to a function which expects a reference to a `std::vector<double>` argument in C++11

Comment: no, the types mismatch, you need to convert before you call in c++

Comment: By 'double pointer' do you mean `double*` or a pointer to another pointer?

Comment: How would the function know the number of elements that are behind the `double*`? This is quite clearly impossible.

Comment: Actually i mean pointer to a double (double *)

Answer (score 1):

That will not be possible, you'll have to copy the data in a vector

```
vector<double> v(ptr, ptr + length);
```

Also, you cannot assign the data behind the pointer directly in the vector, copying is required, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836324/how-to-cheaply-assign-c-style-array-to-stdvector)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than copying the data into a vector, you could also change the function to [take a](https://github.com/microsoft/GSL/blob/master/include/gsl/span) [`span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span). You will still have to include the length along with the pointer.

[e.g.](https://godbolt.org/z/_iFELy)

```
void takes_span(std::span<double>) {}

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> vec = { 1, 2, 3 };
    double arr[3] = { 4, 5, 6 };
    double * ptr = arr;

    takes_span(vec);
    takes_span(arr);
    takes_span({ptr, 3});
}
```